# Won't let me install VSIX extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, discord, vsix

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2013 and I have downloaded an .vsix file called "DiscordRPCVS" and when i run it, it gives me the following error(s). I also tried installing it through Tools>Visual Studio Command Prompt.

[Click here for error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAp1P.png)

And this is the console log error:

`01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - -------------------------------------------
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - Initializing Install...
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - Extension Details...
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  Identifier      : discord_rpc_vs.Company.b011d8bc-b0bf-4cf1-9948-4bf45efb4d54
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  Name            : DiscordRPCVS
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  Author          : Swan
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  Version         : 1.7.0
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  Description     : Enables Discord Rich Presence for Visual Studio 2017
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  Locale          : en-US
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  MoreInfoURL     : 
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  InstalledByMSI  : False
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - 
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  Supported Products : 
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -          Version : [15.0]
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - 
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -  References      : 
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -      -------------------------------------------------------
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -      Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.15.0
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -      Name         : Visual Studio MPF 15.0
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -      Version      : [15.0]
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -      MoreInfoURL  : 
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM -      Nested       : No
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - 
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - 
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - Searching for applicable products...
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Basic Express 2010
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
01-Oct-18 7:35:58 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need VS 2017 to use this extension